# Angular 10 : [objet HTMLInputELEMENT] error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm working with angular 10 and I want to add a row with input type to my existing table when I click on the add button.

Here is my code :

```
export class CsContextComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

@ViewChild('table') table!: MatTable<string>;
contextAttributeKeys!: IContextAttributeKey[];
controls!: FormArray;
displayedColumns: string[] = ['priority', 'name', 'description', 'actions'];
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<ContextAttributeKey>();
dataSchema!: IContextAttributeKey[];
contextAttributeKeys!: IContextAttributeKey[];

addTable(): void {
    const inputName: any = document.createElement("input");
    inputName.type = "text";
    const inputDescription: any = document.createElement("input");
    inputDescription.type = "text";
    const priority: any = this.contextAttributeKeys.length + 1;
    const table: HTMLTableElement = document.getElementById("table") as 
    HTMLTableElement;

    this.contextAttributeKeys.push(new ContextAttributeKey(999, inputName, 
     inputDescription, priority));
     this.table.renderRows();
}
```

html :

```
         <form name="editForm" role="form" [formGroup]="editForm">
         <table mat-table class="table table-bordered table-striped" 
         id="table" #table [dataSource]="contextAttributeKeys" cdkDropList 
         (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
            <!-- Priority Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="priority">
              <th class="col-xs" *matHeaderCellDef> Priority </th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element;let i = index">
                <div class="drag-handle">
                  <ng-container  [ngTemplateOutlet]="dragHandleTmpl">
                  </ng-container>
                {{ element.priority }}
              </div>
              </td>
            </ng-container>

            <!-- Name Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
              <th scope="col" *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
              <td class="col-md" mat-cell *matCellDef="let element;let i = 
              index" id="nameTd">
                <span> 
                  {{element.name}}
                
                </span>
              </td>
              </ng-container>

            <!-- Description Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="description">
              <th scope="col" *matHeaderCellDef> Description </th>
              <td class="col-md" mat-cell *matCellDef="let element;let i = 
              index" id="descriptionTd">
                <span>
                    {{element.description}}
                  </span>
              </td>
            </ng-container>
            <!-- Action Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
              <th scope="col" *matHeaderCellDef>Actions</th>
              <td class="col-xs text-right" mat-cell *matCellDef="let 
              element;let i = index">
                <div>
                <button (click)="onEdit(i)" class="btn btn-warning btn- 
                mini"><i 
                 class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
                <button (click)="delete(element)" class="btn btn-danger btn- 
                mini"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
                </div>
       
              </td>
            </ng-container>

            <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
            <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" 
           cdkDrag [cdkDragData]="row" id="tr"></tr>
          </table>
        </form>
          <br>
    <button id="jh-create-entity" class="btn btn-context shape-semi-round 
    float-right jh-create-entity create-context-attribute-key" 
    (click)="addTable()">
        <fa-icon icon="plus"></fa-icon>
        <span>
        Add
        </span>
    </button>
```

[this is my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCad5.png)

when i click the add button i want to add a new row with priority incremented and 2 input fields for new name and description
i managed to add the row and to increment and diplay priority but i couldn't show the input fields
I got the `[object HTMLInputELEMENT]` instead of the actual input field.

Help, please!

Comment: `HTMLInputElement` is the type of the input element (and that is the correct type), so I can't see what is wrong? Aside from that, I'd recommend to not use this approach of creating elements in Angular (directly manipulating the DOM is discouraged), but create a separate component and a component factory.

Comment: when i push the inputName and inputDescription to contextAttributeKeys i got [object HTMLInputELEMENT] not the actual input to write in .. i will add an image of the table to show you

Comment: `Input` is an object of type `HTMLInputElement` meaning it is the javascript-representation of an `<input>` element in html. It provides all the properties that describe the input in the html. Have a look at the documentation (e.g. `value` property for the text of the input): https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement

Comment: `const inputName: any` would actually be `const inputName: HTMLInputElement` in your code (same for inputDescription). I'd recommend changing that because that will give you intellisense, e.g. for `.type`.

Comment: thank you for your answers but i don't want the value of the input i want to write in it ..im displaying data in my matTable (angular material) and i have an addButton when i click it  a new row shows with the priority incrementing and an input field to add name and description

Comment: when i change it to const inputName: HTMLInputElement i got this error '' L'argument de type 'HTMLInputElement' n'est pas attribuable au paramètre de type 'string' ''

Comment: Might need to add `as HTMLInputElement` to that.

Comment: Writing in the input (assuming you mean via code) is done by setting the value property.

Comment: i edited my post for more information

Comment: writing in the input means i let the user enter a new value for name and description

Comment: Ok, I think there was some missunderstanding. What you mean is that the element, that is inserted into the DOM is not a working input element, e.g. not clickable/editable? In your html you are not creating an input for those two columns though, but spans.

Comment: im retrieving data from contextAttributeKeys and  displaying it with spans but when i add the new row i want 2 input fields for name and description to let the user write new data in it

Comment: In that case you will need to add some logic to the template to distinguish/toggle between span and input (e.g. using *ngIf). Of course you can't bind an input element to a span in a useful way.

Answer (score 1):

With the additional code the problems seems more clear.

You are trying to use a input as string (same as you would enter in browser console `document.createElement('input').toString()`). You would have to get `.outerHTML` from the input node that you have created and then pass this through Angular Sanitizer to create a SafeHtml instance and then you could bind it to `[innerHTML]` input of any element in the template (probably `<div>`).

What you should do instead is to either write a completly new row definition or add a contition inside each cell to replace `{{element.priority}}` with input definition (something like):

```
        <ng-container matColumnDef="priority">
          <th class="col-xs" *matHeaderCellDef> Priority </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element;let i = index">
            <div class="drag-handle">
              <ng-container  [ngTemplateOutlet]="dragHandleTmpl">
              </ng-container>

              <ng-container *ngIf="element.editMode">
                <input type="text" formControlName="priority" />
              </ng-container>
              <ng-container *ngIf="!element.editMode">
                {{ element.priority }}
              </ng-container>

            </div>
          </td>
        </ng-container>
```

Consider this as a suggestion, not final solution. This way you preserve angular bindings and handling of the form and you don't touch raw DOM nodes.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER BELOW: ------------------------------------------**

Not sure why are you directly touching window APIs and raw DOM nodes
But your problem seems to be caused by DOM sanitization or outputting HTML as nodes instead of string into Angular bindings. A broader context would be needed.

In general the concept for that in Angular is to use Components and data binding for each element.

Something like this:

(app-table.component.html)

```
<table formArrayName="list">
  <tr *ngFor="let contextAttribute of contextAttributeKeys; let i = index">
    <td><input type="text" [formControlName]="i" [value]="contextAttribute.priority"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

(app-table.component.ts)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormArray, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-table',
  templateUrl: './app-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-table.component.scss']
})
export class AppTableComponent implements OnInit {

  form: FormGroup;
  contextAttributeKeys: any[];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.contextAttributeKeys = [
      {
        priority: 222,
      },
      {
        priority: 4,
      }
    ];

    this.form = new FormGroup({
      list: new FormArray([])
    });
  }

}
```

This is just an example, please read more about Angular way of handling forms:
https://angular.io/start/start-forms

Comment: thank you for your answers but that's not what i want ..im displaying data in my matTable (angular material) and i have an addButton when i click it a new row shows with the priority incrementing and an input field to add name and description

Comment: @symfony please show the rest of the code then, because it doesn't look like your table was created using angular approach. In my code, to add another input you just need to  push another object to the contextAttrubuteKeys array, angular will handle all the presentation

Comment: @symfony check my updated answer. I hope this will help you.